# AWK print the column number where a match is found

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I looked a lot of places for this answer, but could not find it.  Still learning AWK here, and was just wondering how to print the column number where a match is found.

I want the script to give me the field/column number where regexp match "/1" is found

INPUT

```
name1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0
name2 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
name3 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
name4 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
4
2
2
5
```

Comment: use a `for` loop to loop over the columns, and then print the value of the variable.

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. Please make an attempt, and post what you tried so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ cat adr.txt
name1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0
name2 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
name3 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
name4 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1

$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if ($i ~ "/1$") print i } }' adr.txt
4
2
2
5
```

Comment: You should change `"/1"` to  `"/1$"`, or else it would also match `0/12`

Comment: Worked for me after removing the quotes in the pattern